# How to handle multiple inputs with Logstash in the same file?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

Let's say you have very 3 different lines in your log firewall file and you want:

to grok it and the result be stored into an elastic search cluster using the dedicated elastic search output.

what should i do in my logstash.conf ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the different logs come from the same log source (i.e. the same file) and should be regarded as being of the same type (which is judgment call) you can just list multiple grok patterns:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "pattern1", "pattern2", ..., "patternN"]
  }
}
```

Listed patterns will be tried in order.

If log messages come from different inputs and are completely different, use the type field to distinguish between the different messages:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "foolog" {
    grok {
       match => ["message", "pattern1"]
    }
  } else if [type] == "barlog" {
    grok {
       match => ["message", "pattern2"]
    }
  }
}
```

This pattern might be appropriate also for messages coming from the same input, but that takes a bit more work since you first have to examine the message in a conditional to determine which type to pick.

Comment: You are really very nice because you always answer me, but it does not work this time, if you allow me I'll tell you what I want exactly and try to give me an idea,
my problem is that I have a log file with very 3 different lines, 
this is an example :

Comment: Feb 27 17:38:51 id=firewall time="2015-02-27 17:38:51" fw="GVGM-LYON" tz=+0200 startime="2015-02-27 17:38:50" pri=5 confid=01 slotlevel=2 ruleid=65 srcif="Vlan2" srcifname="ADISTA" ipproto=icmp dstif="Vlan2" dstifname="ADISTA" icmptype=8 icmpcode=0 proto=icmp src=10.16.82.50 dst=10.38.252.131 action=block logtype="filter"#015

Comment: Feb 27 13:17:05 id=firewall time="2015-02-27 13:17:04" fw="GVGM-LYON" tz=+0200 startime="2015-02-27 13:17:03" pri=5 proto=http contentpolicy=1 ruleid=3 op=GET result=302 user= src=192.168.21.29 srcport=49575 srcportname=ephemeral_fw_tcp dst=217.163.21.35 dstport=80 dstportname=http dstname=ads.yahoo.com modsrc=94.127.8.15 modsrcport=62519 origdst=127.0.0.2 origdstport=8080 sent=415 rcvd=0 duration=0.25 action=pass cat_site="ads" arg="/cms/v1%3Fesig%3D1%7E53b2e94cb9cad249de625ca979a6bba56a9267cf%26nwid%3D10000953417%26sigv%3D1" logtype="web"#015

Comment: if you notice they are different , I got only grok the first line and if I add the second one it does not work,
I tried  a lot , but as you know I am a beginner and I do not have many ideas.


Any help please :(

Answer (score 0):

looking at your comments under Magnus post, I can share maybe a bit more specific example.

**Option 1)** The logs from our Fortigate are similar and the related grok filter looks like this:

```
    grok {
        match => [
            "message" , "%{FORTIGATE_50_BASE} %{FORTIGATE_50_V1}",
            "message" , "%{FORTIGATE_50_BASE} %{FORTIGATE_50_V2}",
            "message" , "%{FORTIGATE_50_BASE} %{FORTIGATE_50_V3}",
            "message" , "%{FORTIGATE_50_BASE}"
        ]
        tag_on_failure => [ "failure_grok_fortigate" ]
        break_on_match => false
    }
```

And the related patterns are these:

```
   FORTIGATE_50_BASE %{SYSLOG5424PRI:syslog_index}date=%{FORTIDATE:date} time=%{TIME:time} devname=%{HOST:hostname} devid=%{HOST:devid} logid=%{NUMBER:logid} type=%{WORD:fortigate_type} subtype=%{WORD:subtype} level=%{WORD:loglevel} vd=\"?%{WORD:vdom}\"?
   FORTIGATE_50_V1 srcip=%{IP:srcip} srcintf=\"%{HOST:srcintf}\" dstip=%{IP:dstip} dstintf=\"%{HOST:dstintf}\" sessionid=%{NUMBER:sessionid} status=%{DATA:status} policyid=%{DATA:policyid} dstcountry=\"%{DATA:dstcountry}\" srccountry=\"%{DATA:dstcountry}\" trandisp=%{WORD:trandisp} service=%{WORD:service} proto=%{INT:proto} app=%{WORD:app} duration=%{INT:duration} sentbyte=%{INT:sentbyte} rcvdbyte=%{INT:rcvdbyte} sentpkt=%{INT:sentpkt} rcvdpkt=%{INT:rcvdpkt}
   FORTIGATE_50_V2 user=\"%{PROG:user}\" ui=%{GREEDYDATA:ui} msg=\"%{GREEDYDATA:msg}\"
   FORTIGATE_50_V3 action=\"%{PROG:action}\" tunneltype=\"%{PROG:tunneltype}\" tunnel_id=%{NUMBER:tunnel_id} remote_ip=(%{IP:remote_ip}|\(null\)) tunnel_ip=(%{IP:tunnel_ip}|\(null\)) user=\"%{PROG:user}\" group=\"%{PROG:group}\" dst_host=\"%{PROG:dst_host}\" reason=\"%{PROG:reason}\" msg=\"%{GREEDYDATA:msg}\"
```

So there's a base pattern shared between all logs and some specific parts and the way the grok filter is configured is to handle the more specific patterns first and fall back to the generic one.

**Option 2)** You logs look very much like key value lists, so maybe a simpler `kv`filter will help you much more than any pattern.

In your case it might be as simple as:

```
input {
 ...
}
filter {
  kv { }
  date { ... pull in the date data ... }
}
output {
  ..
}
```

Hope any of that works. In general I also found it very helpful to have some [unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823917/how-to-implement-the-unit-or-integration-tests-for-logstash-configuration) for ever now log format available.

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately the kv filter won't work completely out of the box since there are values with spaces in them. Those values are doublequoted but the kv filter isn't quote-aware.